# How to show just QuerySnapshots with boolean true in ListView? (Dart/Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, cross-platform

I have a Firestore database and I want this ListView (code below) to only show QuerySnapshots if the doc ["status"] in the database is true. The rest of the QuerySnapshots should not be displayed.

I hope you can understand what I'm trying to do. If you don't like to ask I'll try to explain it better again.

I appreciate help. Thank you and have a nice day.

Thats my code:

```
Widget _buildList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final doc = snapshot.docs[index];
        return Card(
          elevation: 4,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(doc["subject"]),
            subtitle: Text(
                "\n" +
                    "Datum und Uhrzeit: " +
                    doc["date"] +
                    "  -  " +
                    doc["time"] +
                    "\n\n" +
                    "Infos: " +
                    doc["person"] +
                    "  -  " +
                    doc["driver"],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 8, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.clear),
              color: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
              onPressed: () {
                new DatabaseService()
                    .setRequest(snapshot.docs[index].id, false);
                showCupertinoDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
                    content: Text("Möchtest du noch eine Notiz eingeben?"),
                    actions: [
                      CupertinoDialogAction(
                          isDefaultAction: true,
                          child: new Text("Ja"),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            showCupertinoDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                  new CupertinoAlertDialog(
                                title:
                                    Text("Wie soll deine Nachricht lauten?\n"),
                                content: CupertinoTextField(
                                  controller: _noteController,
                                ),
                                actions: [
                                  CupertinoDialogAction(
                                      isDefaultAction: true,
                                      child: new Text("Ok"),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        if (_noteController.text.isEmpty) {
                                          Scaffold.of(context)
                                              .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                            content: Text(
                                                "Bitte gebe eine Notiz ein!"),
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                CupertinoColors.inactiveGray,
                                          ));
                                        } else {
                                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                          new DatabaseService().updateNote(
                                              snapshot.docs[index].id,
                                              _noteController.text);
                                        }
                                      }),
                                  CupertinoDialogAction(
                                    child: Text("Abbrechen"),
                                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                      CupertinoDialogAction(
                        child: Text("Nein"),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Die Anfrage wurde abgelehnt!"),
                  backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
                ));
              },
            ),
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.check_mark),
              color: CupertinoColors.systemGreen,
              onPressed: () {
                new DatabaseService().setRequest(snapshot.docs[index].id, true);
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                  content: Text("Die Anfrage wurde angenommen!"),
                  backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.systemGreen,
                ));
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter docs in advance:

```
Widget _buildList(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
final docs = snapshot.docs.where((el) => el["status"]).toList();
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final doc = docs[index];
...
```